# Basecamp API - Can I use URL parameter key Values with GET Requests

Tags: basecamp

Example:

https://basecamp.com/1234567/api/v1/projects.json?archived=false

I do not think this works. Although the server returns with 200 status code and all the projects versus just the projects which are not archived.

Answer (score 1):

We don't support those parameters.  Instead, you could request all of the projects https://github.com/basecamp/bcx-api/blob/master/sections/projects.md, and then request the archived projects: GET /projects/archived.json.  From there, you can work out your active projects.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `GET /projects.json` only returns active projects, so there's no need for an `?archived=false` flag.